# After setting CSS zoom value, jQuery.position() returns different results in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, zooming, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to get position top/left of an element:

```
<span id="test_span" style="float:right;width:100px;height:100px"></span>

console.log('Position Left = ' + $('#test_span').position().left);
```

Edge: Position Left = 100
Chrome: Position Left = 100

However if I set the zoom value to 0.5, the results of the two browsers are different:

```
body{
    zoom: 0.5;
}

console.log('Position Left = ' + $('#test_span').position().left);
```

Edge: Position Left = 50 //100 *0.5 = 50
Chrome: Position Left = 100

Is there a way to get same result without detecting browsers?

Comment: Do you have some text in your span? A text maybe with `font-size` measured in `rem`?

Comment: It's empty span tag...